# Should I try to understand the tutorial or should I learn from scratch?

Tags: vb.net

My primary interest in programming, my motivation and what keeps me going, is to be able to write a program using the Betfair API. My skills however are extremely basic.

I was reading a text regarding improving your reading performance, and it suggested an approach of reading headlines and summaries first before focusing on details. The principle is to keep yourself interested and motivated avoiding unnecessary information. The text suggested flexible reading on what you consider important skipping walls of text you are already familiar with or with little use.

The above got me thinking.

I found an introductory tutorial about Betfair API on their forums: http://forum.bdp.betfair.com/showthread.php?t=112

I had a glance through it and I am not familiar with the syntax (yet)

The question to experienced programmers is:

a) should i skip the tutorial until I have finished reading a text book in VB.NET?
b) should I focus on a textbook in VB.NET concurrently with the tutorial? To keep me interested and motivated?
c) should I focus on the tutorial, perhaps using trial and error, asking questions in forums or searching online for things I don't understand?

I guess my ultimate goal is not to learn VB.NET but to be able to write a working application. If its not the goal its what motivates me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know the basics of vb.net, you can study it while taking the tutorial of the api you study!

But what helps you improve most is while studying this two, think of a project that you may work with while studying it, because applying it is what makes you learn most!